# PHP update mysql table, subtract by 1

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do a ticketing system. When the user has registered successfully, subtract the available ticket seats by 1.

```
$AvailSeats = $_POST['myAvailSeats']; //3

//Once registration info entered, minus Available Seats

$sql = "UPDATE tblcourseinfo SET
        AvailSeats = --$AvailSeats
        WHERE CourseID = '$CourseID'";
```

However when this statement is queried, my `AvailSeats` was updated to `0` instead of `2`. My data type is int for `AvailSeats`. Why is this happening?

EDIT:

Thanks everyone who helped me. Here is the solution that everyone has provided:

```
$AvailSeats = $_POST['myAvailSeats']; // 3

//Once registration info entered, minus Available Seats

--$AvailSeats; // Decrease the seat by 1 first

$sql = "UPDATE tblcourseinfo SET
        AvailSeats = --$AvailSeats
        WHERE CourseID = '$CourseID'";
```

Comment: Why not use `$AvailSeats - 1` instead?

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought.

Comment: What if you make it like `$AvailSeats = $_POST['myAvailSeats'] - 1;` and `AvailSeats = $AvailSeats`?

Comment: $sql = "UPDATE tblcourseinfo SET
        AvailSeats = AvailSeats -1 
        WHERE CourseID = '$CourseID'";

Comment: why not `UPDATE tblcourseinfo SET
        AvailSeats = AvailSeats - 1
        WHERE CourseID = '$CourseID'`?I don't understand why are you decreasing the value of the php variable `$AvailSeats`. :-/

Comment: Yes you guys are right. There wasn't a need to decrease the value of the variable. I was doing this because I did a small check on the previous page to check if the ticket is `0` and forbid registration. The queries you all have provided still does not work. It is still being updated to 0.

Comment: try to deug the query, just print out the query and execute it directly it into mysql window and see what is happening there.

Comment: It's solved, thanks everyone. There was a bug somehow with my browser. Your solutions were all correct. Sorry about it.

Comment: Agree with Remy's Answer.

Comment: You don't need the `--` in `--$AvailSeats` - all it's doing is negating the value twice (the SQL it produces will be `SET AvailSeats = --2` in the solution). SQL doesn't treat it as a decrement operator as you're used to from the PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If AvailSeats already had value, subtract it directly from mysql may work:

```
$sql = "UPDATE tblcourseinfo SET AvailSeats = AvailSeats - 1 WHERE CourseID = '$CourseID'";
```

Or just subtract `$AvailSeats` before the query.

Answer (score 3):

just store your value in a variable and subtract 1 from there and pass it to the query

```
$AvialSeats = $currentSeats - 1; 
$sql = "UPDATE tblcourseinfo set  AvailSeats = $AvialSeats  WHERE CourseID = '$CourseID'";
```

Comment: yeah its same as ur comment just wanted to show how will look like as u have given the right suggestion